# Spotting Admin keys

Tags: immutable

Doing some research on a few different Ethereum contracts. Is there a good way to tell if a contract has admin keys to invalidate tokens in a wallet or change the code after deployment? Basically I want to make sure the code is immutable

If possible can you list some examples. I know the contract for AAVE has one or two https://etherscan.io/address/0x7fc66500c84a76ad7e9c93437bfc5ac33e2ddae9#code

what would I be looking for to spot it in the code?

Let me know if I did not explain myself enough.

Answer (score 0):

super hard.  Usually just going to etherscan and going through the code is the safest bet, but even if a contract is immutable (no admin key), a lot of time they have other issues that act essentially as an admin key.

Use an oracle? Do they have an admin key (LINK does...)

Have a DAO/token weighted voting?  How sure are you that one party doesn't control a majority of voting tokens?

Even in the case of something like Uniswap, the front end is centralized, so you need to be sure you know how to access your tokens if they remove support.  Also if one party controls all the liquidity, are you or someone else prepared to step in to fund the pool if it goes dry?  Is it an issue for you if you have to wait (e.g. using them as a price feed)

@chrisblec does a good job on twitter calling people out, but finding trusted people who deep dive this stuff is probably your best bet.